# How to implement caching using etag in Angular 6?

Tags: http, caching, https, angular6, etag

Is there a sample code on how to implement HTTP caching using etag header in Angular 6? I read the [angular-http-etag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-etag) but it's not that clear for me. I want to cache a resource (get/post request result). Example of API https://api.icndb.com/jokes/3?escape=javascript

I want to be able to call a same API, e.g. /jokes/3, through a HttpClient.get() from different places. If the cache has not expired then I want to take the local cache instead of fetching from the remote database again, unless the get parameter or post body has changed, e.g. /jokes/4.

The package angular-http-etag weekly download is around 100 and I haven't been able to find an example using the package in angular 2+.

(Another alternative I read is the caching through RxJS sharedReply)

Thanks.

Comment: Http caching is handled by the server and the browser. Your client code doesn't have to do anything to take advantage of it. Also note that that the `ETag` header does not cause anything to be cached, it's used for revalidation of already-cached data.

Comment: What if I just want to get the cache result from an API 1st call and the API can be called from different pages? How does the caching work? Is it per resource, e,g. a call to a same API, or per page?

Can I assume some configuration must be set up at the server side?

Comment: Instead of using etag, we decided to implement RxJS caching locally (on client side without incurring any HTTP call). This strategy works because we only cache constants, e.g. country name and id, which seldom change.